# How to create a responsive client logo gallery

Tags: html, css, flexbox, gallery

I've been working on a website and I would like to make a logo gallery of my clients. I've been struggling on the internet with some tutorials, but none seem to fit to my needs. I've been looking into grids but I think I prefer a simple flexbox solution. Preferably I've four/six logos next to each other on desktop, and two per row on mobile.

What would you recommend?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klGkR.png)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
     <div id="client-logos">
         <img class="logo" src="/resources/images/logo_vdbp.webp" alt="Logo Van de Bovenste Plank">
         <img class="logo" src="/resources/images/logo_nrc.webp" alt="Logo NRC">
         <img class="logo" src="/resources/images/logo_keeperstalent.webp" alt="Logo Keeperstalent">
         <img class="logo" src="/resources/images/logo_veloscout.webp" alt="Key2Finance">
     </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #client-logos {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used bootstrap v4? it offers a Grid option that could be very useful to your code, more details on the following link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/

With it you could set the page to show things like this:

```
3 col  3 col  3 col  3 col  = 4 pic / desktop

6 col  6 col = 2 pic | mobile
6 col  6col  = 2 pic |
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like to build the website without bootstrap. :-)

Comment: okay, you can learn Media query, breakpoint by CSS. I do not remember more.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose I am suggesting you to learn all about CSS grid because it is mostly used to create gallery. and I am familiar with one of the tutorial in which you will know all about CSS grid and how to make gallery  and I think the channel name is free code camp.
and if this helps let me know and up vote.

Comment: I followed the web dev simplified tutorial about grids and managed to make one. Thanks!

Comment: I gave you an upvote, but my account is not advanced enough yet to show it publicly. :-)

Comment: @Jurrian ok but don't forget